# Why I get error on my query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I use entity framework 6.

I have this array:

```
int?[] regionTypeId = [1,2,3];
```

In this query (linq to query):

```
    var t = (from sites in context.Set<Site>()
             where regionTypeId.Contains(sites.Regions.Select(x=>x.RegionTypeId).ToList())

            select sites).AsNoTracking<Site>();
```

I get this error:

```
Error 15 'int?[]' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Contains<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, TSource)' has some invalid arguments
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: `int?[] regionTypeId2=[1,2,3];` is not valid C# syntax. If you used valid syntax, `Contains` works just fine: http://rextester.com/BILY38938

Comment: You might try changing to a List<int>().

Comment: Also you said you have an array `regionTypeId2` then use `regionTypeId.Contains` which is just another indication that what you've posted is not your actual code.

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension method `Contains(this IEnumerable<int?> source, int value?):bool` doesn't accept a `List<int>` or `List<int?>` but in this case accept only an `Nullable int` aka `int?`

Comment: I tried this:

regionTypeId.Contains(sites.Regions.Select(x=>x.RegionTypeId).ToArray()

But still it not works

Comment: This is the logic, not sure about the implementation: `sites.Regions.Where(x=> regionTypeId.Contains(x.RegionTypeId‌​))...`

Comment: I tryed it But now I have this error:

Error 12 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Playground.Models.SiteRegion>' to 'bool'

Comment: seems I need to set some condition

Comment: Instead of Where use any and then select

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your declaration, The following code works fine for me :

```
int someValue=1;
int?[] regionTypeId =  { 1, 2, 3 };
if (regionTypeId.Contains(someValue))
{
   // code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are trying to execute `int?[].Containts(List<int>)`. Specify your whole error next time.

> 'int?[]' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best
>   extension method overload
>   'Queryable.Contains>(IQueryable>, List)'
>   requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable>'

Why not just make your `int?[]` to `int[]` and use it in linq.

```
 var result = regionTypeId.Where(x => x != null).Cast<int>().ToArray();
```

And after that your linq:

```
  var t = (from sites in context.Set<Site>()
         where result.Contains(sites.Regions.Select(x=>x.RegionTypeId).ToList())

        select sites).AsNoTracking<Site>();
```

Comment: Nope the problem is not this. Check my answer, the problem is related to the wrong use of Contains

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] regionTypeId = new int[] {1,2,3};

var t = (from sites in context.Set<Site>()
    where regionTypeId.Contains(sites.Regions.Select(x=>x.RegionTypeId))
    select sites).AsNoTracking<Site>();
```

1. Fixed your array of ints.
2. Removde the `ToList`, the contains block will be evaluated on the database server.

Answer (score 0):

Tinwor was the only one to spot that you don't execute the expected ...

```
regionTypeId.Contains(someInteger)
```

... but ...

```
regionTypeId.Contains(some IEnumerable<int>)
```

... which obviously is the wrong parameter. But he didn't show the correct alternative, which is

```
var t = from site in context.Set<Site>().AsNoTracking()
        where site.Regions.Any(x => regionTypeId.Contains(x.RegionTypeId))
        select site;
```

This checks if a site has at least one `Region` whose `RegionTypeId` is in `regionTypeId`.